# OpenCV for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

Installation instructions: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

I have downloaded everything. Everything seems to be working except when I run this sample program:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat m  = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    System.out.println("m = " + m.dump());
}

}
```

I get the output:

```
m = [1, 0, 0;
     0, 1, 0;
     0, 0, 1]
```

(which I hope is right).

But I also get these error messages:

```
objc[63784]: Class CVWindow is implemented in both /Users/.../cv2.so and /Users/... /libopencv_java246.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[63784]: Class CVView is implemented in both /Users/.../cv2.so and /Users/.../libopencv_java246.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[63784]: Class CVSlider is implemented in both /Users/.../cv2.so and /Users/.../libopencv_java246.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[63784]: Class CaptureDelegate is implemented in both /Users/... /cv2.so and /Users/jsuit/opencv/lib/libopencv_java246.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I have tried moving the cv2.so file to another folder, but then the program won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do, as far as I can make out, with a reference to the Python libraries (the .so version) that ends up included within the Java libraries themselves.  This would seem to be a build configuration error (following the instructions does produce it).

I was able to eliminate the double-definition error by re-building the Java version without support for the Python libraries in it, using the following in the cmake step (all else the same):

```
cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=NO ..
```

The newly produced Java libraries and .jar work just as before, but without the error message.

(Note that I can't guarantee this won't cause other problems, especially if you want to do some sort of mixed-language programming, but it does produce libraries useful for Java and Eclipse.  You can always build multiple versions of OpenCV, too, some with support for Python, some without, and use whichever one you like if you switch languages at some point.)

Hat tip:  http://answers.opencv.org/question/16015/mac-opencv-246-java-exception/